# develop a java app which will run at taskbar and will show a popup on condition matching

Tags: java

I am working on an app which will ping the multiple urls (servers) at regular intervals to ensure whether the server is running fine or it's going down. I have completed the coding part(java program) to achieve this.

Here is the code is :

```
public class PingServers {

  public static boolean pingUrl(String address) {
    try {
        final URL url = new URL("http://" + address);
        final HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 100); // Timeout is in milliseconds
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        urlConn.connect();
        final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (urlConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            System.out.println("Time (ms) : " + (endTime - startTime));
            System.out.println("Ping to " + address + " was success");
            return true;
        }
    } catch (final MalformedURLException e1) {
        System.out.println("inside MalformedURLException");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        System.out.println("inside Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(address + " is either going down or is an unknownhost.");

    }

    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

    //for periodic execution
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Execution in Main Thread...." + i);
        Date now = new Date(); // initialize date
        System.out.println("Time is :" + now); // Display current time
        String url1 = "www.google.com";
        String url2 = "www.yahoo.com";
        String url3 = "www.invalidurl.com";
        pingUrl(url1);
        pingUrl(url2);
        pingUrl(url3);

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        if (i == 5) {
            System.out.println("Application Terminates");
            System.exit(0);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

It's running well in cmd (console). But I need to form it as an App which will be running in taskbar automatically and as soon as the condition is matched (server goes down or unknownhost) it will show the pop-up.

Would anyone please tell me the best way to achieve this(Step by Step) from here onwards.

It would be highly appreciable.

Comment: [How to Use the System Tray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)

Comment: I tried SystemTray also but the 'SystemTray.isSupported' returns 'false'. (I am using windows7 32bit).

Comment: Well, I've never had that happen before, without it, you're, frankly, screwed.  Are you running as the administrator?

Comment: yeah... I am running as the administrator.